# Print the same array, it is different in different functions, why?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program to solve the shortest path between two points in a circuit wiring. I use the `BFS(breadth search first)` method. I save the path in the path array, but I find that the coordinates of the last point in the path are not what I want (sometimes the value is correct and sometimes not).So, I printed out the path array in the `findPath` function, which was correct, but not correct in the main function.Why?

What's wrong with my description?I am not a native English speaker and my English is not particularly good.Please point out if what I said is not clear.
English retrieval ability is still poor, I do not know if this problem is repeated.If repeated please forgive me!
Thank you very much!

```java
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<queue> 
using namespace std;

const int M = 9;
const int MAXLEN = 30;

class Point
{
public:
    int x;  
    int y;
};
//The increments in the x and y direction,
// in the order of up, right, down, and left
int dx[4] = {0,1,0,-1};   
int dy[4] = {-1,0,1,0};

void findPath(int G[][M],Point start,Point finish,int& pathLen,Point path[])
{
    //Find the shortest path from start to finish and its length, pathLen
    if(start.x == finish.x && start.y == finish.y)     //Two overlapping
    {
        pathLen = 0;
        return ; 
    } 
    Point cur,next;
    G[start.x][start.y] = 1;                //Start of blockade
    queue<int> qx,qy;                       //Coordinates the queue 
    qx.push(start.x);    qy.push(start.y);  //The starting point enters the queue 
    while(!qx.empty())
    {
        cur.x = qx.front(); qx.pop();      // 'cur' stands for current position
        cur.y = qy.front(); qy.pop();
        for(int i = 0;i < 4; i++)
        {
            next.x = cur.x + dx[i];  next.y = cur.y + dy[i];   // next is the next position 
            if(!G[next.x][next.y])              //The location is not marked 
            {
                G[next.x][next.y] = G[cur.x][cur.y] + 1;            
                if(next.x == finish.x && next.y == finish.y)    //Finish line 
                {
                        break;
                }   
                qx.push(next.x);
                qy.push(next.y); 
            } 
        }
        if(next.x == finish.x && next.y == finish.y) break;   //Finish line 
    } 

    //Structural path 
    pathLen = G[finish.x][finish.y]; 
    cur = finish;
    for(int i = pathLen-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        path[i] = cur;      //Record current position
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)          //Look for the previous position 
        {
            next.x = cur.x + dx[j];         
            next.y = cur.y + dy[j];
            if(G[next.x][next.y] > -1 && G[next.x][next.y] < G[cur.x][cur.y]) 
            {
                break;
            } 
        }
        cout<<"path["<<i<<"]="<<path[i].x<<","<<path[i].y<<endl;
        cur = next;  //Move to current position
    } 
} 

int main()
{
    int G[M][M];          //Grid map
    Point start,finish;   // The starting point and end point 
    int pathLen;          //Shortest path length 
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)  //Initializes the outer fence as -1 
    {
        G[0][i] = G[M-1][i] = G[i][0] = G[i][M-1] = -1; 
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < M-1; i++)    //Initialize the region in the grid to 0
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < M-1; j++)
            G[i][j] = 0; 
    }

    G[5][1] = -1; G[6][1] = -1; G[6][2] = -1; G[6][3] = -1; G[7][1] = -1;
    G[7][2] = -1; G[7][3] = -1; G[1][3] = -1; G[2][3] = -1; G[2][4] = -1;
    G[3][5] = -1; G[4][4] = -1; G[4][5] = -1; G[5][5] = -1;     // Inside a wall
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)   //Initial time map
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            cout<<setw(4)<<G[i][j]; 
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    start.x = 3; start.y = 2; finish.x = 4; finish.y = 6;
    Point *path = new Point[M]; 
    findPath(G,start,finish,pathLen,path);
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)   //Complete time map
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            cout<<setw(4)<<G[i][j]; 
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < pathLen; i++)
    {
        cout<<"path["<<i<<"]="<<path[i].x<<","<<path[i].y<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**
As you can see in the figure below, the `path[9]` output in the `findPath` function is different from that in the `main` function.
[image]

**Sometimes the results are right**

[image]

Comment: Trick that can save you a lot of trouble setting up maps: https://ideone.com/ghoNW0

Comment: My [Rubber Duckie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know how you can get `path[9]` out of an array that's only valid 0..8.

Comment: @user4581301 thank your help,I have found the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valgrind says:

```
==27791== Invalid read of size 4
==27791==    at 0x401B7B: main (delme.cpp:113)
==27791==  Address 0x4daf108 is 0 bytes after a block of size 72 alloc'd
==27791==    at 0x4839593: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:433)
==27791==    by 0x401A03: main (delme.cpp:101)
==27791== 
==27791== Invalid read of size 4
==27791==    at 0x401BA6: main (delme.cpp:113)
==27791==  Address 0x4daf10c is 4 bytes after a block of size 72 alloc'd
==27791==    at 0x4839593: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:433)
==27791==    by 0x401A03: main (delme.cpp:101)
```

you are accessing erroneous bytes (outside your allocated memory)

the line reported by valgrind is

```
    cout<<"path["<<i<<"]="<<path[i].x<<","<<path[i].y<<endl;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I found the mistake.`Point *path = new Point[M]`should be `Point *path = new Point[M*M];`

Comment: @ClancyZeng. Another option is [to use `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You can `push_back` (or `emplace_back` if you're compiling to one of the more recent C++Standards) `Points` into the `vector` and it will resize itself to fit.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, I should have used `std::vector`. I'll remember next time.Thany you again!

Comment: @ClancyZeng as an added bonus, `vector` has an `at` method that throws an exception if the program wanders out of bounds. The extra checking slows a program down, but it's very helpful in finding bugs like this. Once found, you go back to using `[]`

Comment: @user4581301 Ok, I see！